# Question About Regions In PSN

Tags: ps4, psn

I just wanted to ask for example if I have a region 2 PSN account and buy a region 1 disc, is gonna be a problem for running it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There will be no problem running it but you cannot get any preorder content, DLC, or anything else associated with a code since it will be tied to the store in region 1.  You can get around this if you'd like by creating an account in region 1 and making your PS4 the main PS4 of that account which will share all content from that account with other accounts on your PS4.  As a side note, this will not work with all games since some DLC is tied to an account you have with a company rather than your PSN account.  In my experience, this happens with Bethesda games which I bought from the US store and played on a Japanese account because the content was bound to an account on the Bethesda website which could not be linked to multiple PSN accounts.

TLDR: If you don't plan on getting DLC/do not have preorder content, the game will work fine.  Playstation 4s are not region locked.